# Raspberry Pi / Linux - ntp cron job cause 100% cpu (/etc/cron.daily/ntp)

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi, cpu-usage

I am using a `Raspberry Pi 3`. Sometimes, the process called `ntp`, which is actually `/etc/cron.daily/ntp`, causes *100% cpu usage* for hours and days until I stopped the process by commands. It seems that it stucks and run forever.

The `top` looks like this:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
25706 root      20   0  3852 1028  856 R  97.8  0.1   3580:45 ntp
```

The `/etc/cron.daily/ntp` file itself looks like this. I think it may be what RaspberryPi adds to the system, so I also post this code.

```
#!/bin/sh

# The default Debian ntp.conf enables logging of various statistics to
# the /var/log/ntpstats directory.  The daemon automatically changes
# to a new datestamped set of files at midnight, so all we need to do
# is delete old ones, and compress the ones we're keeping so disk
# usage is controlled.

statsdir=$(cat /etc/ntp.conf | grep -v '^#' | sed -n 's/statsdir \([^ ][^ ]*\)/\1/p')

if [ -n "$statsdir" ] && [ -d "$statsdir" ]; then
    # only keep a week's depth of these
    find "$statsdir" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;

    # compress whatever is left to save space
    cd "$statsdir"
    ls *stats.???????? > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # Note that gzip won't compress the file names that
        # are hard links to the live/current files, so this
        # compresses yesterday and previous, leaving the live
        # log alone.  We supress the warnings gzip issues
        # about not compressing the linked file.
        gzip --best --quiet *stats.???????? 
        return=$?
        case $return in
            2)
            exit 0          # squash all warnings
            ;;
            *)
            exit $return        # but let real errors through
            ;;
        esac
    fi
fi
```

So where does the problem lie? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem? I've got similar situation...

Comment: @Waszker No. Still have it.